# Paypal [error 10004] Invalid arguments on DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Tags: paypal

I'm having problems capturing Paypal payment through **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** method. Paypal failed and returned with only one 10004 error which said

> Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.

However, Paypal did not specify which argument was invalid.

Is there a way to request Paypal to provide more details in this case?

Below are arguments which I post to Paypal using the NVP API.

**DoExpressCheckoutPayment**

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Hieu+Nguyen
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=20
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=20
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=20
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=452435243
EMAIL=hieu%40thirststudios.com
METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment
VERSION=124.0
PWD=[masked]
USER=[masked]
SIGNATURE=[masked]
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Fhakuba.centralsnowsports.com.au.local%2F%3FACT%3D53%26G%3DVXdJWStNWGFNSTIvQ09mNmE1cXJWSXlDN0lqYXlQdnNZRjBHL2NoaWpMNVAwNGlaN1A2K1crNVRBbUpmNG1yY05NTC9Mb1hHUVBQL0VsTG9rUEFzbFE9PQ%3D%3D%26M%3DVldsZFNoZVVsRTBJNjFLbmxZSWRtbitQVkZvNEI1M2hrQXNUb2hBZHozQnhCcUVFZkJmM3B0VVBvek1vV3ZPdGpubXJuQlNHd1FaU01wcDNYZVlGMVE9PQ%3D%3D
CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Fhakuba.centralsnowsports.com.au.local%2F%3FACT%3D53%26G%3DejNhR1BDSlhRZ1o0MzZoWFAvVmttY2pzMzF5amhqbDZzV2NMemoxbjcvY2dPQTZ4ZlVtL0ltRUx0dmkwUlV0Y3dpRDBuUWxJNk12cnREVDQ4Z1NYMWc9PQ%3D%3D%26M%3DR013TVBmL1FHZkRtOWVRSzVUL0JqMmZYa1B4RTJVNFptdjBPSGJFTlJqK2VSdkU5V25FczM4WEs2WkcwK3FPaWxwYkFSaW1JbGpHOVJSbWpTRjR4N3c9PQ%3D%3D
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=JPY
ALLOWNOTE=0
CHANNELTYPE=Merchant
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly
LOCALECODE=US
ADDROVERRIDE=0
NOSHIPPING=1
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
TOKEN=EC-59S20038JL208993V
PAYERID=XAC7EG8Y2M5D6
IPADDRESS=hakuba.centralsnowsports.com.au.local
```

**[Updated]** more API call argument

**SetExpressCheckout**

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Physical
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Hieu+Nguyen
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=20
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=20
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=20
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=3143214
EMAIL=hieu%40thirststudios.com
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
VERSION=124.0
PWD=[masked]
USER=[masked]
SIGNATURE=[masked]
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Fhakuba.centralsnowsports.com.au.local%2F%3FACT%3D53%26G%3DRlN5WWJUS21HeGd6cTlSTm95MFpZMkxTTTdMZEZ1OUV6S2FIY0pYSjVnM1M0d2FjQjVIQnlqQ3F2d3NFSHRhZHB3bTVnRUE3T1NzN0EwOTcvOVlIQ3c9PQ%3D%3D%26M%3DYWNEUGhhemNVRzNpM0liMEVSUi94TmxkRDZRdmM2R3UrTUh0c2x1dFgwZ2tTNHJjV2lRUHBMWjR6d29vTkxXa3VRUnRPM0xNcnoyYlNHV2NKU2kzb2c9PQ%3D%3D
CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Fhakuba.centralsnowsports.com.au.local%2F%3FACT%3D53%26G%3DWnJzWDBWU1JaZndldStIY1FUNjFUWlNyTWYwR0N4NlRQK0VnajAvRjF2bFViZlVhZWphU0o3M1Z5dlNrdWlHOG4rRGd6OUdHNHJQaVhMa0tzamZvcnc9PQ%3D%3D%26M%3DemsxeGV1cnZ4a2JVWnhZRHNaU0ExTHBOaEp6dUQ1b2hiTVF5MXVxMjZyaFh1aFRhUGQvZ0M3dlZGT2dFU0FUelU3bjR6Qm5VVFBLT2xPSlJTN3ROUmc9PQ%3D%3D
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=JPY
ALLOWNOTE=0
CHANNELTYPE=Merchant
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly
LOCALECODE=US
ADDROVERRIDE=0
NOSHIPPING=1
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

**GetExpressCheckoutDetails**

```
METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails
VERSION=124.0
PWD=[masked]
USER=[masked]
SIGNATURE=[masked]
TOKEN=EC-75541725B7341060R
```

Comment: In SetExpresscheckout, did you pass the same currency ? PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=JPY

Comment: Yes, I did. Let me try get the arguments from SetExpressCheckout and post it here. Btw, the process was working fine but only failed in the recent days.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error as of February 20th, PayPal Express payments were working fine previously and no configuration changes on my end had been made.  I am also handling JPY as my receiving currency.  I'm wondering if there was a configuration change relating to this and will be calling PayPal about it shortly.  Will report back any info.

Comment: Additionally, I should mention that the error messages received in my case are: [L_ERRORCODE0] -> 10004 , [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] -> Internal Error [L_LONGMESSAGE0] -> Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.

Comment: We have a known issue in PayPal system for JPY currency and 10004 error in sandbox environment. Engineer team work on this issue.  Please change the currency or wait for several days to test it again.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Zhao.  I hope the issue is able to be resolved soon so I can re-enable PayPal Express payments on my site.  I may also explore the option of allowing payment in other currencies.

Comment: Thanks for the update Zhao. I will try to test the Gateway again in a few days and see how it goes.

Comment: Any further update to this situation?  I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: For the record, the problem resolved itself after a few days. This must be an issue with Paypal internal engine. Still, we ended up moving away from Paypal after this incident.