# Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details (#10004: Internal Error)

Tags: api, magento, paypal

I have cloned a Magento CI 1.9.2.3 site and I am getting this Paypal error:

> Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details (#10004: Internal Error).

The weird thing is that the site it was cloned from works perfectly...

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Have you [done any research into the error code?](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1122&actp=LIST)

Comment: yes but the 10004 error seems to relate to a bunch of things going by paypals api doc https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

Comment: It seems to suggest either invalid data in some way or rate limiting errors - which I doubt you're hitting. Have you checked all your Magento and server logs for exceptions?

Comment: I've been getting the same error since late February.  Is the payment currency in JPY?  There was a response a while back from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616103/paypal-error-10004-invalid-arguments-on-doexpresscheckoutpayment -- however nothing has come of it yet.  Might be best to give PayPal tech support a call.

Comment: Yes JPY I had to hire a dev to patch in the end

Comment: Can you give any info about what the dev did in the patch?  A clue about what the error might actually be in?